# Gif not completing animation on inactive component

Tags: java, animated-gif, jtabbedpane

I am trying to display an **animated Gif** on a `button click` in a `JTabbedPane` (GIF loop only once). The animation is working fine but the problem is:

- When I switch to **another tab during animation**, and then **come back**, the **GIF starts animation from start again** (animation not completing on background)
- If I **stay in** the animation tab **until animation is completed** then switch back and fourth then its fine.
  [image]
  My Question is:
  **Why animation do not complete in the background when the tab is not active?** How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you put the animation code in a thread and implement it in the main class, then it can run in the background.

Comment: its already in thread. and I am not using any special library for animation. Just `jLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(...))` perfectly working